# ASP.NET 3.5 ClientIDs refined

Tags: asp.net, clientid

I've created a simple ASP.NET 4.0 application to see how rendered client ids will vary if I change `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion` in web.config and `ClientIDMode` attribute of the control.
Now I've set `<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5"/>` and `<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Message" ClientIDMode="AutoID" />` and expect to find in the generated markup asp.net-3.5-style ClientID (something like id='ctl00_Message'),
but I see this `<span id="Message">Hello world!</span>`.

Why does not ASP.NET render it as a 3.5-style id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the span is on it's own, then there is no reason to change the ID.

It depends if the control is inside another control. If the span above is inside a Repeater, DataList etc, then the Id will change.